# Dual Boot goes Read Only

Tags: dual-boot, readonly, veracrypt

My Machine dual boots windows 10 and Bunsenlabs.
Hard drives are encrypted with VeraCrypt.
The second Hard drive became read only now (one internal one external).

**Peculiarity**

Windows created "$RECYCLE.BIN" and "System Volume Information" folders on both internal and external hard drives. usually I could just delete them under Linux. When I boot into Bunsenlabs and mount the internal hard drive in VeraCrypt, it is read/write. As soon as I touch a single file in those two folders, the drive goes read only. It also goes read only when I backup with backintime.

**Things I tried:**

- chmod -R 777 as root
- Thunar as root
- mount in VeraCrypt under different path
- disabled fast startup under windows and rebooted (Linux and Windows)
- Use a command line tool under windows to delete "$RECYCLE.BIN" and "System Volume Information" folders, I cannot remember which one now

**a)** How can I make the drive permanently r/w again?

**b)** how can I get rid of "$RECYCLE.BIN" and "System Volume Information" folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I thought I might as well try windows' own check and recovery tool (right click on hard drive --> tools). And what do you know, it did just that.

Problem solved.